# Send content as RAW to printer, from a webpage

Tags: .net, web, printing

I work with a Desktop application that have a sofisticated .NET code handling of printing. This question concern a related .NET object used when the output must be transformed into RAW, for direct delivery to printer.

For this specific example a dot-matrix printers is used, later on also other kind printer required RAW is subject for this. The desktop application is ported into a web solution and the those printers won't be replaced "just because". How do you solve printing as RAW from webbrowsers?

Sidenotes,
The environments is Windows Computers with printer drivers installed. I think we can add/change the printer settings to whatever, if it may be of help.

[Edit]
This component https://code.google.com/p/jzebra/ appear to be successfully used for this purpose. And I also find this, http://neodynamic.com/products/printing/raw-data/aspnet-mvc. Either of them have any deeper research from my side.

Looks like a third party plugin is required to perform this, is that the only way available?

Comment: I assume that downvoters should act constructive. Please, some respect to us who spend time to ask.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/322091) - it details how to send a RAW print request directly to a printer using .Net.

Comment: Thank's. Please help me, what part of that page tell how to send the RAW formatted string from a webbrowser?